# Failure to read from QtcpSocket

Tags: qt

I need some serious help. i have failed to figure out the cause of the problem.
i have a client server application am trying to develop. in this application, i request a file from the client and the server sends that file. the server side seems to be occur but i get a problem on the client side. with a large file, the client tcpsocket fails to read the last bytes sent by the server. the server shows that the bytes are sent but the client shows that its still waiting for these bytes. here is the code

The server code

/*copies or transfers a file to a target*/

```
 void TcpConnecton::copyFileFunction(){

  QTcpSocket* socket;

  switch(copyFile.operation){

    case 1:
        socket = getSocket();
        break;

    case 2:
        socket = tcpSocket;
        break;
}

FileObject fileObject;
QFileInfo fileInfo(copyFile.filePath);
QString file_Name(QString(tr("%1/%2")).arg(copyFile.remoteDestination).arg(fileInfo.fileName()));

fileObject.setFilename(file_Name);

QFile file(copyFile.filePath);

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;

if(fileInfo.size() <= 2*1024){
    {
        QByteArray block;
        QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

        QByteArray filebytesRead = file.readAll();

        fileObject.setFileData(filebytesRead);

        out << quint32(0) << quint32(3) << fileObject;
        out.device()->seek(0);
        out << quint32(block.size() - sizeof(quint32));

        socket->write(block);
        socket->waitForBytesWritten();

        qDebug() << "file bytes read" << filebytesRead.size();
        qDebug() << "file object data" << fileObject.getFileData().size();
        qDebug() << "file size" << fileInfo.size();
        qDebug() << "block size" << block.size() - sizeof(quint32);

    }
}else{

    while(true){

        QByteArray filebytesRead = file.read(2*1024);

        if(filebytesRead.size() == 0) break;

        fileObject.setFileData(filebytesRead);

        {
            QByteArray block;
            QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

            out << quint32(0) << quint32(3) << fileObject;
            out.device()->seek(0);
            out << quint32(block.size() - sizeof(quint32));

            socket->write(block);
            socket->waitForBytesWritten();

            qDebug() << "file bytes read" << filebytesRead.size();
            qDebug() << "file object data" << fileObject.getFileData().size();
            qDebug() << "file size" << fileInfo.size();
            qDebug() << "block size" << block.size() - sizeof(quint32);
        }
    }

}

fileTransfered.transfer_Operation = (copyFile.operation == 1)? 1 : 2;
fileTransfered.fileName = copyFile.filePath;

QByteArray block;
QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

out << quint32(0) << quint32(7) << fileTransfered;
out.device()->seek(0);
out << quint32(block.size() - sizeof(quint32));

tcpSocket->write(block);
//tcpSocket->flush();

switch(copyFile.operation){
    case 1:
        socket->deleteLater();
        break;
}

qDebug() << "filetransfer object transfered" ;
```

}

The client Code

```
void FileTransferSystem::readResponseData(){
    QDataStream in(&tcpSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

    if(nextblockSize == 0) {
       if (tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint32)) return;
       in >> nextblockSize;
     }

    if(tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() < nextblockSize) return;

     responseByteArrayData = tcpSocket.read(nextblockSize);


    qCritical("Data received..... " );
    qDebug() << " block size received: "<< (int)nextblockSize;
    qDebug() << " responseByteArrayData received: " <<     responseByteArrayData.size();

   dispatchResponse();

   nextblockSize = 0;

 }

void FileTransferSystem::dispatchResponse(){

   quint32 cmd;
   QDataStream in(&responseByteArrayData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);
   in >> cmd;

   qDebug() << " command received: " << (int)cmd;
   QString path;
   switch((int)cmd){        

    case 5:
        in >> copyFileObject;
        handleGetCopyFile_Object();
        break;
    case 7:
        in >> fileTransferedObject;
        handleGetTransferedFile_Object();
        break;        
    case 9:
        in >> path;
        newFolderCreated(path);
        break;
    default:
        qCritical("unknown command..... " );
        return;
   }
}

void FileTransferSystem::handleGetFileObject_Object(){

   QFile file(fileObject.getFilename());

   if(file.exists()){

   file.open(QIODevice::Append);
   file.write(fileObject.getFileData());
   file.close();

}else{
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);//will create the file if it does not yet exist
    file.write(fileObject.getFileData());
    file.close();
 }

}
```

with small files (2kb) the client receives all the bytes but with a larger file the client fails to read the last bytes sent by the server. where am i going wrong. please help

Comment: Are you on Windows? This note says that WaitForBytesWritten() may fail on Windows. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForBytesWritten

Comment: seek(), waitForBytesWritten() and especially write() have return values which you should check.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, many calls related to I/O such as `read()` and `write()` return status variables that you must check to ensure the proper execution of the operation.

As an example I will be quoting from the documentation of [QIODevice::write()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) here:

> qint64 QIODevice::write(const char * data, qint64 maxSize)
>
> Writes **at most** maxSize bytes of data from data to the device. Returns
>   the number of bytes that were actually written, **or -1 if an error
>   occurred**.

TIP: many examples that come with Qt contain snippets of code that show how to use read/write properly, accounting for the return codes.